# How can I prevent certian IP from connecting to iSCSI target server by ufw?

Tags: firewall, ufw, iscsi

I set up a iSCSI target with targetcli.
I would like to pass all connections to access target storage but a few IPs.
I did it as below:

```
ufw allow 3260/tcp
ufw deny from 192.168.0.112 to any port 3260 proto tcp
ufw deny from 192.168.0.200 to any port 3260 proto tcp
```

But I found the connection is still allowed after I establish the rule.
The only measure to stop the traffic between them is:

```
ufw deny 3260/tcp
```

Are there any ways to ban the traffic from certain IPs by ufw?

Answer (score 0):

First I did "ufw default deny incoming; ufw default allow outgoing" then did "ufw allow 3260/tcp; ufw deny from 192.168.0.112 to any port 3260 proto tcp;
ufw deny from 192.168.0.200 to any port 3260 proto tcp".
But it didn't work. This situation is applicable to every kind of services.
So, I skipped the second step, "ufw allow 3260/tcp", and add "ufw allow in from IP" rule for the IP address which I allow to let it in.
Then it works. This applies to other services as well.
Therefore, I conclude ufw or iptalbe doesn't allow more than two-stage rules which could conflict each other. Even though it is logical.